# How come Win+R prompt can open Python when it's not in my path?

Tags: windows, command-line, path

When I use the run prompt in Windows XP Professional (Win+R), and type `python.exe` or `python`, it works and greets me with the python prompt.

However, when I start a `cmd` window, and then type `python.exe` or `python`, it doesn't find it.

This is what I expect, as the Python directory (for me, `I:\Python31\`) is not in my `PATH`.

How come, then, that if I type `python.exe` in the Win+R prompt, it works?

Edit: here is a partial output of `SET`, I removed most irrelevant entries, I'm not sure why is it useful, apart from the `PATH` variable which I already said doesn't include the Python directory. If you need a particular variable other than these, please ask.

```
CLIENTNAME=Console
CommonProgramFiles=I:\Program Files\Common Files
ComSpec=I:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
OS=Windows_NT
Path=I:\WINDOWS\system32;I:\WINDOWS;I:\WINDOWS\system32\WBEM;I:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;I:\Qt\2010.05\mingw\bin;I:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.PSC1
ProgramFiles=I:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=I:
SystemRoot=I:\WINDOWS
VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=I:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
windir=I:\WINDOWS
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the output of `SET`?  You may want to edit it so that you name does not appear.

Comment: Posted parts of it, not sure how anything else than `Path` is relevant, do you want a specific variable?

Comment: What's your working directory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the Run prompt searches a registry path for programs to launch as well as the %path%. Take a look at `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` - you'll likely find a node called "Python.exe" with the default entry pointing to the Python executable. Installers *should* add registry entries for all main executables here, but the Run prompt is an underappreciated feature, so a lot of developers forget to add this simple step to their installer.

Comment: Never knew about this myself, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Technically it is `ShellExecuteEx()` that does the lookup.

Comment: In fact, there are several places in the registry where paths are located, for example `HKCR\Applications`. One day I should clean them all out.